# R (auto.arima function): number of lags in KPSS test

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, stationarity

I am working with `auto.arima`. If I got this correctly, `auto.arima` depends on a `ndiffs` function to find how many differences we need to make the series stationary. The default test for stationarity in this case is KPSS.

I searched a bit (source: https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/unitRoot.R) and I found that the number of lags is:

```
use.lag = trunc(3*sqrt(length(x))/13))
```

Am I right? If so, why is it calculated like that?

Comment: I suspect that the answer is "experience". If you don't get an answer here, you may want to ask the package author, Rob Hyndman. If you get an answer from him, it would be great if you could post it here for later generations. Or even better, point him to this post, and he may answer here, [he's a frequent CV poster](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman).

Answer (score 2):

In the original [KPSS paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(92)90104-Y), the recommended lag value was the integer part of $4(T/100)^{1/4}$ where $T$ is the length of the series. This is also the default in the `urca::ur.kpss` function.

The `tseries::kpss.test` function uses the default lag equal to the integer part of $3T^{1/2}/13$. It is not clear to me where this choice came from.

For several years, the `ndiffs` function in the forecast package used the tests from the tseries package with the default settings. In v8.3, we switched to the urca package because it had more options available. To make things as backwards-compatible as possible, we kept the lag at the default value from the tseries package.